# Objective C - Photo Framework - Is there a way to save Metadata with image?

Tags: ios, metadata, photosframework

I'm writing an iPhone app that takes photos using iphone's camera and saves a copy in photo collections (not sandbox) and also saves a copy to our Server.

How do I include the meta data (GPS, creation date and everything else) and save it to the copy of the image I am saving on the Server ?

From researching I understand that apple saves the metadata in a separate Database, is there a way to access that database ? Is there any way to save that information with the image itself ?